# Editing a form -> Forced to modify image [Easy to answer i think]

Tags: forms, image, symfony, upload, edit

I am trying to modify my profile entity but in it i have a variable for the profile image path ($avatarPath). But when i am trying to modify my entity with a form i am forced to "upload" a new file for validated the form (the value of the path file is at null for default i think, so when i accept the form without an image the tells me that my form is not valid and it lack the image

so my goal is to set by default the image of the profile in the edit form or to not put the button upload but making the form work (and i will put the upload file in an other page)

(that's for sure an idiot error but i don't see where)

My $avatarPath

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter an image")
 * @Assert\Image()
 * @ORM\Column(name="avatar_path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $avatarPath;
```

My controller :

```
/**
 * Creates a new profile entity.
 *
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="profile_edit")
 */
public function editProfileAction(Request $request, User $user, Profile $profile)
{
    $loggedAs = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProfileType::class, $profile);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        /**
         * @var UploadedFile $file
         */
        $file = $form->get('avatar_path')->getData();
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName);

        $profile->setAvatarPath($fileName);
        if ($profile->getAvatarPath() == NULL)
            $profile->setAvatarPath('NULL');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        $user->setIdProfile($profile);
        $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em2->persist($user);
        $em2->flush();



        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/user/new_profile.html.twig', array(
        'profile' => $profile,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'loggedAs' => $loggedAs,
    ));
}
```

My form :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('resume')
        ->add('is_male')
        ->add('birth', BirthdayType::class, array(
            'years' => range(1930,2018)
        ))
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'label' => 'form.email'
        ))
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('language')
        ->add('travel')
        ->add('pets')
        ->add('avatar_path', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null
        ))
        ->add('avatar_path', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false
        ));
}
```

Thx for anyone who will try to help :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the property `mapped => false` to the `avatar_path` field in your Form.

Doing this will cause symfony to do two things. The first is to ignore the `avatar_path` field when validating the form which happens in your controller when `form->isValid()` is called. Secondly symfony will not assign any value to the field which happens when you call `$form->handleRequest($request)`.

If you choose to use the `mapped => false` property you will need to manually set the `avatar_path` on the `Profile` entity.

Here is the documentation from symfony http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/file.html (these docs are for symfony 3.4)

Hope this helps.

Edit: I assume the form is failing the validation checks because of the two `@Assert` Statements in your Entity. Looking at your code I think you can safely remove those since you are already allowing the property `$avatarPath` to be nullable anyway.

Comment: i will try to add manually avatar path thx :) and that was it the dooble assert :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I put that :

```
->add('avatar_path', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ));
```

but nothing appens always the same : [image: Error]

That just refresh the page so the form is not valid ...